# If statement to flag only certain values?

Tags: excel

Essentially, I want a specific IF formula to trigger when C2>B2, but also I want it to take notice when B2 is anywhere between 0-1000 more than C2. Anything past 1000 is fine.

So far I have `=IFNA(IF(C2>B2,"Flag",""),"") & ""` but how would I say, "Also flag when B2 is only 0-1000 more than C2, as well"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another method is to use an `OR` statement:

```
=IF(OR(C2-B2>0,B2-C2>=1000),"FLAG","")
```

Comment: I also have no idea why I didn't just think of `=IF(B2-C2>1000,"","Flag")`, but your solution worked too

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
=IF(C2-B2>0,"FLAG",IF(B2-C2>=1000,"FLAG",""))
```

You simply want to nest conditions as the false or true eventuality of a previous IF.